# JavaScript: Selected text is not getting replaced when the text is inside a textarea

Tags: javascript, html, replace, selection

I have a problem replacing a selected text inside a *textarea* with a predefined replacement text.

To replace a text, I have to select it and right click.

The replacement happens properly, if the text is inside a `<div>` or a `<p>` tag. But if the text is inside a `<textarea>`, it is not getting replaced correctly.

A sample is available in this **[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qLm2qwzw/1/)**

Here is my **code:**

HTML:

```
<p> Select any text in this sentence and right click to replace it </p>

 <div>
  <textarea name = "intro" rows = "5" cols = "80">This text is not getting replaced as expected
  </textarea>
</div>
```

JS:

```
if (document.addEventListener) {
    document.addEventListener('contextmenu', function(e) {
        replaceSelectedText("<<replaced>>");
        e.preventDefault();
    }, false);
} else {
    document.attachEvent('oncontextmenu', function() {
        alert("You've tried to open context menu");
        window.event.returnValue = false;
    });
}

function replaceSelectedText(replacementTxt) {
    var sel, range;
    if (window.getSelection) {
        sel = window.getSelection();
        console.log(sel);
        if (sel.rangeCount) {
            range = sel.getRangeAt(0);
            console.log(range);
            range.deleteContents();
            range.insertNode(document.createTextNode(replacementTxt));
        }
    } else if (document.selection && document.selection.createRange) {
        console.log("!!")
        range = document.selection.createRange();
        range.text = replacementTxt;
    }
}
```

Is there something wrong with the way I implemented it?

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Still looking into it but I believe I know part of the problem. It seems when you right-click, it isn't selecting the `textarea`, rather it ends up selecting the parent div. Not sure if that helps you get moving more.

Comment: I'm working on it.. Thanks for the info..

Comment: Ahh I found the problem. [Here's a relevant question.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19953220/use-window-getselection-get-selected-or-cursor-located-text-line-from-textarea) Apparently textarea uses a different selection API so you have to use selectionStart and selectionEnd properties. Hope that helps more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the text inside a textarea cannot be accessed using `window.getSelection`.

To access the text, there are different selection API namely `selectionStart` (The index of the beginning of selected text) and `selectionEnd` (The index of the end of selected text).

Here is the JS **code:**

```
function ShowSelectionInsideTextarea(replacementText, eleID)
{
    var textComponent = document.getElementById(eleID);

    if (textComponent.selectionStart != undefined)
      {
        var mainStr = document.getElementById(eleID).value;
        var startPos = textComponent.selectionStart;
        var endPos = textComponent.selectionEnd;
        selectedText = textComponent.value.substring(startPos, endPos);
        mainStr= mainStr.replace(selectedText, replacementText);
        document.getElementById(eleID).innerHTML=mainStr;      
      }
}
```

Here is a live **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/qLm2qwzw/9/)**

Comment: The problem with this solution is when you have multiple occurrences of the text that you wish to change. This function will only change the first occurrence of such text since there’s no way to get the index of the occurrence. A better solution would be to split the main string at the selectionStart, perform the replace on the rightmost piece and then join it back.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `.value` to change the text of the textarea.

Look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18387540/javascript-string-replace-in-textarea)

Comment: Still not working.. If you see my Fiddle, the replacement text is displayed but not in the correct place inside the textarea.

Comment: You can´t add it to the textarea with `.insertNode` The textarea text is not a DOM element. You must use value to get the string, alter the text and write it back in the textarea with `.value()`

Answer (score 0):

The range container that you get for the selected text in the `textarea` is the `div` itself and not the `textarea` element. Therefore, when you try to insertNode a replacement text, it becomes a sibling of the `textarea`.

More information from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25790778/how-can-i-prevent-range-selectnode-selecting-too-much-of-the-dom-when-attempti).

> The problem with textarea elements is that they do not hold their contents in DOM nodes. The text value is a property of the element. When you call range.selectNode, what happens is that the range is set so as to encompass the node you pass to the function and the children node of this node, but since a textarea does not store its text in children nodes, then you select only the textarea.

You need to string replace by using the text area's selection properties and manipulate the string itself and not the DOM.